# angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker hide in jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have some unexpected behavior when a UI Bootstrap datepicker is inside a jQueryUI dialog. When the calendar button is clicked, the datepicker is shown inside the dialog, but the dialog does not resize, so the datepicker is mostly hidden inside it, and you have to use scroll bars on the dialog to see it all.

[This Plunker shows the issue.](https://plnkr.co/edit/K4ke1JSVPzWREjpWrcV3?p=preview)

Is it possible to pull the datepicker over the dialog?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false
      });
        });

        angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
        .controller('ctrl', function(){})
    </script>
    <style>
        .glyphicon { font-size: 20px !important; }
    </style>
</head>    
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup
                               ng-model="date" is-open="open">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open = true">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Does someone know how to fix that?

Comment: Why are you mixing bootstrap and jQuery UI? why don't use use the bootstrap model instead of jQuery UI dialogue?

Comment: @TJ - I too wondered why he'd mix the two but this would still be a problem with the bootstrap modal.  Either way the modal either has to be sized or resized to handle the datepicker in its open state.

Comment: In my project i must simulate desktop so jQuery dialogs are better, beside i belive bootstrap modals are undraggable.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm not a big fan of using watchers in angular, this seems like a good use for one.  You could put a watch on the $scope variable 'open' and resize the dialog accordingly.  The controller would look like this:

```
 .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    var originalHeight = 100;
    var originalWidth = 250;

    $scope.$watch('open', function() {
      var newHeight = originalHeight;
      var newWidth = originalWidth;

      if ($scope.open) {
        newHeight = newHeight * 4;
        newWidth = newWidth * 1.5;
      }

      $("#dialog").dialog({
        height: newHeight,
        width: newWidth
      });
    });
  });
```

You may want to get originalWidth and originalHeight from the #dialog element but for this example I simply hardcoded it.

Comment: Your solution works but is it possible to picker flow over dialog instead of resizing it?

Comment: @PawełMizio - I'm not aware of any way of doing this other than resizing the dialog.